# Creating a site collection in a unit test

Tags: 2013, unit-testing

The following code throws an UnauthorizedAccessDenied exception (0x80070005) when run as a unit test in MSTest, however it works when run on a web page. The `username` is my domain user:

```
[TestClass]
public class MyTests
{

    [TestMethod]
    public void Blah_ValuesGiven_SiteCreated()
    {
        //Arrange
        SPUserToken sysUserToken = null;
        using (SPSite spfarmSite = new SPSite("http://myserver.com"))
        {
            string username = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

            //Exception thrown here:
            SPSite newSite = spfarmSite.SelfServiceCreateSite("http://myserver.com/sites/UnitTestSiteCol", "Unit test Site Col", 
                "Unit test Desc", 1033, 15, "STS#1",
                username, "Unit Test", "unit@test.com", null, null, null, null);

            //Act ...
            //Assert ...

        }
    }
}
```

I'm using MSTest in Visual Studio 2012 for SharePoint 2013 and have "Default Processor Architecture" set to X64

`http://myserver.com/sites` is a managed path

I tried using a user token but it didn't help:

```
        SPUserToken sysUserToken = null;
        using (SPSite tempSite = new SPSite("http://myserver.com"))
        {
            sysUserToken = tempSite.SystemAccount.UserToken;
        }
        using (SPSite spfarmSite = new SPSite("http://myserver.com", sysUserToken))
```

Adding RunWithElevatedPrivileges didn't help

Comment: What lines are failing in each example?

Comment: SPSite newSite = spfarmSite.SelfServiceCreateSite

Comment: Have you verified that 'username' is the value that you would expect during the unittest?

Comment: You're correct, the difference is the user - The unit test is running as me, the web request version is running as NTAUTHORITY. Maybe I can impersonate during the unit test...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your process account does not have access to the SharePoint databases! Open a SharePoint Shell as administrator and use the [Add-SPShellAdmin](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607596.aspx) Cmdlet to grant your unit test process account full access to the SharePoint configuration database and the SharePoint content databases. Your code works in a SharePoint web context because the IIS Application Pool account has write access to the SharePoint content databases.